# dropdownlist in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

query needed to update the values in dropdownlist which is inside the listview.
then the values of dropdownlist should be filled particular table in database using c#,ASP.NET

```
protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    float TrSsb;
    float AchSsb;
    if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        TextBox txtSysmoid = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtSysmoid");
        DropDownList drpRegion = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("drpRegion");
        DropDownList drpMoName = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("drpMoName");
        TextBox txt1stWeekTar = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt1stWeekTar");

        TextBox txt1stWeekAch = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt1stWeekAch");
        TextBox txt2anWeekTar = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt2anWeekTar");
        TextBox txt2anWeekAch = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt2anWeekAch");
        TextBox txt3rdWeekTar = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt3rdWeekTar");
        TextBox txt3rdWeekAch = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt3rdWeekAch");
        TextBox txt4thWeekTar = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt4thWeekTar");
        TextBox txt4thWeekAchv = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txt4thWeekAchv");
        Label lblTotlTar = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotlTar");
        Label lblTotlAchv = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblTotlAchv");

        float Trnumber1 = float.Parse(txt1stWeekTar.Text);
        float Trnumber2 = float.Parse(txt2anWeekTar.Text);
        float Trnumber3 = float.Parse(txt3rdWeekTar.Text);
        float Trnumber4 = float.Parse(txt4thWeekTar.Text);
        //float Trtotal = float.Parse(lblTotlTar.Text);

        TrSsb = Trnumber1 + Trnumber2 + Trnumber3 + Trnumber4;

        lblTotlTar.Text = TrSsb.ToString();

        float Achnumber1 = float.Parse(txt1stWeekAch.Text);
        float Achnumber2 = float.Parse(txt2anWeekAch.Text);
        float Achnumber3 = float.Parse(txt3rdWeekAch.Text);
        float Achnumber4 = float.Parse(txt4thWeekAchv.Text);
       // float Achtotal = float.Parse(lblTotlAchv.Text);

        AchSsb = Achnumber1 + Achnumber2 + Achnumber3 + Achnumber4;

        lblTotlAchv.Text = AchSsb.ToString();


        if (TrSsb >= AchSsb)
        {

            string updateCommand = "update om_DailyMoWiseCollection_Rpt set om_Region = '" + drpRegion.SelectedValue + "',om_Mo_Name = '" + drpMoName.SelectedValue + "',om_1stWeek_Target = '" + txt1stWeekTar.Text + "',om_1stWeek_Achv = '" + txt1stWeekAch.Text + "',om_2ndWeek_Target = '" + txt2anWeekTar.Text + "',om_2ndWeek_Achv = '" + txt2anWeekAch.Text + "',om_3rdWeek_Target ='" + txt3rdWeekTar.Text + "',om_3rdWeek_Achv ='" + txt3rdWeekAch.Text + "',om_4thWeek_Target ='" + txt4thWeekTar.Text + "',om_4thWeek_Achv ='" + txt4thWeekAchv.Text + "',om_total_Target ='" + lblTotlTar.Text + "',om_total_Achv ='" + lblTotlAchv.Text + "' Where om_sysmo_id = '" + txtSysmoid.Text + "'";
            SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please post part of code.

Comment: why would you use a Query to update your values in the drop-down list?  Are they coming out of a database already?  You can just use mydropdown.items.add('anitem');

Comment: Hi Tony,

the listview shows the database value. if i need to update the particular value i need it. value i have to change is in dropdownlist which is inside the listview. query please

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a DataGridView instead.  These support doing drop down lists in cells and have tighter database integration.  When adding a column in the UI designer you get the option to specify a DataGridComboBoxColumn for the type of column.

The reason I would do it is purely simplicity and speed of completing the task.

To do what you want in a listview requires measuring the location of the subitem of interest...etc. That can be tricky when the user has scrolled around a bit.